# PHP MySQL INSERT query no longer works (was working yesterday)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a problem with an INSERT query.

Here is the problem:
Yesterday I was using this code to upload data, it was working fine. Today, when I hit submit on the form, it just shows a blank page. No errors, just blank. Nothing in the error log. All SELECT queries are working fine, so the SELECT Count(id) query still works.

Here is what I have tried:

- Re-uploading to server
- syntax adjustments eg '".$v.'" instead of '$v'
- adding print lines to check that none of the variables are null. All is okay, all data is present just before the INSERT query.
- Test insert via PHP my admin, all okay
- The function call is correct - it is and remains unchanged from Yesterday

The function takes a list of species, a family and a genus, then adds them to the database.
Here is the code (the un-santised version - both were working yesterday):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');




    function submit($family, $genus, $species){


        //require statement
        require 'databaseConnect.php';

        //get num of species
        if(!($result = mysql_query("SELECT Count(id) as num FROM speciesList", $connection))) mysql_error();
            $nums = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $num=$nums[0];

        //parse species 
        $holder="";
        $array = Array();

        while(strlen($species)!=0){
            if($species[0]==';'){
                $array[] = $holder;
                $holder="";
            }else{
            $holder = $holder . $species[0];

            }

            $species=substr($species, 1);

        }

        foreach($array as $v){
            $num++;
            if(!(mysql_query("INSERT INTO speciesList VALUES($num, '$family', '$genus', '.$v')", $connection))){
                mysql_error();
            }else{
                print "success ";
            }
        }
        mysql_close($connection);
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance, this problem is rather mysterious to me!
Em

Comment: Don't guess. Debug.
What is an error message? What is final form of statement? 
Just print it on the screen.

Comment: Echo out `"INSERT INTO speciesList VALUES($num, '$family', '$genus', '.$v')"` and copy the exact call into Workbench or another DB program and it will tell you why it didn't work.

Comment: What is a sample of the value of `$species`?  If your array is empty, the loop won't insert anything.

Comment: What is the . in `'.$v'` for?

Comment: It's because PHP MySQL INSERT queries don't work on Mondays.

Comment: `I'd made a change to the database layout yesterday night` \*sigh\* The sort of thing worth noting in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You never *ever* want to use string replacement with parameters to build SQL statements as it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Instead, bind your parameters.

Your code isn't returning an error because you call `mysql_error()` and ignore the return value. It returns the error string, so you want your code to be more like this:

```
if(!(mysql_query("INSERT INTO speciesList VALUES($num, '$family', '$genus', '.$v')", $connection))){
    print_r( mysql_error() );
}else{
    print "success ";
}
```

If you need help understanding the error once you see it, please post it here.

Comment: +1 for reminding about prepared statements.
Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Thank you all for helping me spot my errors and suggest improvements.

I'd made a change to the database layout yesterday night and thought "I'll remember to change that in my function tomorrow".

It works fine now!

(I use access software, and can get impatient and skip through things that I think I can remember!)

Comment: That's one of the things that version control can help you with!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(!(mysql_query("INSERT INTO speciesList VALUES($num, '$family', '$genus', '.$v')", $connection))){
               echo mysql_error();
            }else{
```

There maybe other things that are amiss, but the mysql_error() function returns a string.  Your script needs to take some action to display the string.

I find that a better way of doing this is to construct the variables separately, so they can be displayed.  And I'm not sure you want that dot before $v.  See if this makes sense to you.

```
foreach($array as $v)
{
    $num++;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO speciesList VALUES($num, '$family', '$genus', '$v')";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$res) die("FAIL: $sql BECAUSE: " . mysql_error());
    echo "<br/>SUCCESS: $sql";
}
```